# Problem: "arguments imply differing number of rows: 0, 29604"

Tags: r

I am new to r and am using a template given to me for an assignment. The goal for the entire code is to take large data sets, plot them, and make the plot more legible.

Here is the code for one of the lines:

```
fatigue.norm <- data.frame("time"=fatigue$time[1:length(fatigue.norm)], "Tricep Signal"=fatigue)
```

Here is the error code from that line

> Error in data.frame(time = fatigue$time[1:length(fatigue.norm)], `Tricep Signal` = fatigue) : 
>     arguments imply differing number of rows: 0, 296064

Can someone explain what this error means, and how I can go about fixing it?
 Packages running:

```
zoo, matlab, signal, ggplot2, pracma, purr, dplyr
```

Comment: `data.frame` columns need to have the same length, i.e. they cannot have a "differing number of rows". The error is telling you that one of the two arguments to `data.frame()`, which are `fatigue$time[1:length(fatigue.norm)]` and `fatigue`, has length 0, and the other has length 296064 (probably in that order) and so you can't make a `data.frame` from them. Check what `fatigue.norm` is.

Comment: In the environment window for fatigue.norm it says `Large ts (294017 elements, 2.2Mb`

Comment: Expanded: fatigue.norm says `Time-Series [1:294017] from 1028 to 295044: 0.922 0.923 0.923 0.923 0.924 ...`

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow ! Any chances you mixed up between `fatigue` and `fatigue.norm` datasets in the selection of datasets used for creating the final dataframe ? Maybe you can edit your question and add the output of `dim(fatigue)`, `dim(fatigue.norm)` and `length(fatigue$time)` just to check the dimension of each object you are trying to use.